# Can a hierarchy type class change its variable type to inheriting type?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

Lets say I have a class. (the example is going to be somewhat silly and inefficient but its just to make a point)

```
Public class Node
    Private children as new list(of Node)
    Public Sub removeChild(n as Node)
        children.remove(n)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I inherit that class and make some additions

```
Public class BookNode
    Inherits Node
    Public title as string
    Public sub removeChildByTitle(t as string)
        For i = 0 to children.count-1
            if (children(i).title = t) then removeChild(children(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End class
```

But this is where we run into a problem. children(i) is a type of Node and doesn't have a variable called title. I could cast the reference into a BookNode to do the comparison or I could declare children as a list (of object) instead.. but the former is clunky and makes it harder to read while the latter is computationally inefficient.

Is there a way for the methods and variables dealing with their own class to be automatically recasted into whatever class inherits them?

Comment: Casting to BookNode seems reasonable to me.

Comment: It is reasonable, on the other hand though, there is literally no downside to automatically recasting self references(unless they are shared or something). I was thinking maybe vb developers thought of that and added a little extra something for user comfort.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `children` isn't accessible in `BookNode` because it's `Private`.  You need to make it `Protected`:

```
Public class Node
    Protected children as new list(of Node)

    Public Sub removeChild(n as Node)
        children.remove(n)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Also, the proper way to do what you need is to do what you suggested, which is to cast each one into a `ChildNode` instance for the comparison:

```
Public class BookNode
    Inherits Node

    Public title as string

    Public sub removeChildByTitle(t as string)
        For i = 0 to children.count-1
            if (DirectCast(children(i), ChildNode).title = t) then removeChild(children(i))
        Next
    End Sub
End class
```

Finally, I would suggest that you use a property instead of a field for `children`.  There are plenty of reasons to do so which I'm not going to expound here.  So:

```
Public class Node
    Protected Property Children as list(of Node)

    Public Sub New()
        Children = New List(Of Node)
    End Sub

    Public Sub removeChild(n as Node)
        children.remove(n)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I am curious though, why property? I wouldn't even know what to google.

Comment: Google "fields versus properties.  A couple reasons: you can't bind to fields and you can't control read/write access to fields.